# Contador que não conta

Tags: python

Olá fiz o seguinte programa:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import datetime
import os
import sys

ref_arquivo = open("trata.txt","r")

for linha in ref_arquivo:
    valor = linha.split(" ")
    recebido0=0
    send0=0
    recebido1=0
    send1=1
    if (valor[0] == "0"):
        if ( valor[1] == "RECEBIDO" ):
            recebido0 = recebido0 + 1
            print ("RECEBIDO 00000")
        elif ( valor[1] == "SENDING" ):
            send0 = send0 + 1
            print ("SEND 00000")

    else:
        if (valor[0] == "1"):
            if ( valor[1] == "RECEBIDO" ):
                recebido1 = recebido1 + 1
                print ("RECEBIDO 11111")
            elif ( valor[1] == "SENDING" ):
                send1 = send1 + 1
                print ("SEND 1111")

print ("=========================")
print ('Recebidos [0] =', recebido0)
print ('Enviados [0] =', send0)
print ("=========================")
print ('Recebidos [1] =', recebido1)
print ('Enviados [1] =', send1)

ref_arquivo.close()
```

Este programa pega a linha de um arquivo txt, retira o primeiro caracter (0 ou 1) e faz a condição (IF). Independente do retorno da condição, entra em um segunda condição para verificar se é SEND ou RECEBIDO.
Seguindo os prints, está funcionando, porém quando verifico os contadores, ele não é incrementado.
A nível de esclarecimento, são 9 RECEBIDOS, sendo 5 do zero e 4 do 1 e 33 SENDING, sendo que após execução os contadores possuem

```
=========================
Recebidos [0] = 0
Enviados [0] = 0
=========================
Recebidos [1] = 0
Enviados [1] = 1
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Os contadores estão sendo declarados dentro do loop, dessa maneira eles são resetados toda iteração, eles tem que ser declarados antes do loop.

Comment: Faltou postar o conteúdo do arquivo trata.txt para a comunidade poder testar o teu código.

Answer (score 1):

estava dando uma olhada no seu código. Você deve realizar 2 ajustes, as variáveis de contadores devem estar fora do loop e deve remover o **\n** da variável valor.

```
import datetime
import os
import sys

ref_arquivo = open("trata.txt","r")

recebido0=0
send0=0
recebido1=0
send1=1

for linha in ref_arquivo:
    valor = linha.split(" ")
    valor[1] = valor[1].replace('\n','')

    if (valor[0] == "0"):
        if ( valor[1] == "RECEBIDO" ):
            recebido0 = recebido0 + 1
            print ("RECEBIDO 00000")
        elif ( valor[1] == "SENDING" ):
            send0 = send0 + 1
            print ("SEND 00000")

    else:
        if (valor[0] == "1"):
            if ( valor[1] == "RECEBIDO" ):
                recebido1 = recebido1 + 1
                print ("RECEBIDO 11111")
            elif ( valor[1] == "SENDING" ):
                send1 = send1 + 1
                print ("SEND 1111")

print ("=========================")
print ('Recebidos [0] =', recebido0)
print ('Enviados [0] =', send0)
print ("=========================")
print ('Recebidos [1] =', recebido1)
print ('Enviados [1] =', send1)

ref_arquivo.close()
```

Resultado da variável **valor** do código antigo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado do código atualizado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não funcionou usando a linha valor[1] = valor[1].replace('\n','')

Comment: O erro foi Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "le.py", line 16, in <module>
    valor[1] = valor[1].replace('\n','')
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Seu conjunto de dados vem nesse formato ?
0 RECEBIDO
1 SEND
1 SEND
??

Comment: Mais ou menos. Ele vem, por exemplo: 0 SENDING BEACON #0

Comment: Isso porque tratei o arquivo. Pois na verdade eu tentei fazr um split neste formato: 0.203537606789    SN.node[1].Application                   SENDING BEACON # 0                mas deu o mesmo erro

Comment: consegue colar duas linhas do seu arquivo aqui ? pelo que entendi ele não quebra linha

Comment: vou colar as linhas originais e depois as que eu tratei. Se puder me ajudar com o split para tratar o original, será maravilhoso.

Comment: 0.22755189537     SN.node[0].Application                   SENDING BEACON # 0
0.22755189537     SN.node[0].Application                   Sending [Beacon] of size 105 bytes to communication layer
0.231689895368    SN.node[0].Communication.Radio           TX finished (no more pkts in the buffer) changing to RX
0.231689895368    SN.node[1].Communication.Radio           Received packet (WC_SIGNAL_END) from node 0, with no interference
0.231699895368    SN.node[1].Application                   RECEBIDO BEACON #0 - ORIGEM 0 - SALTOS 0

Comment: existe muitos espaço entre o double inicial e SN.xxx bem como muitos espaços antes do SENDING ou RECEBIDO

Comment: depois tratei o arquivo e ficou assim

Comment: 0 SENDING BEACON # 0
0 Sending  Beacon 
0 Buffered  BypassRouting packet
0 SET STATE to TX,
0 completing transition to 1
0 Sending Packet, Transmission will
1 START signal from node
0 TX finished (no more
1 END signal from node
1 Received packet (WC_SIGNAL_END) from
0 SET STATE to RX,
0 completing transition to 0
1 RECEBIDO BEACON #0 -

Comment: 0 SENDING BEACON # 0

Comment: 0 Sending  Beacon

Comment: 0 completing transition to 1

Comment: 1 START signal from node

Comment: 1 Received packet (WC_SIGNAL_END) from

Comment: 1 RECEBIDO BEACON #0 -

Answer (score 0):

Como comentado, os contadores estão sendo inicializados a cada loop com o valor zero, pois estão "participando" do loop.

Para resolver, basta que os mesmos sejam inicializados uma vez só, estando fora do loop.

Código com o mesmo exemplo corrigido:

```
import datetime
import os
import sys

ref_arquivo = open("trata.txt","r")

valor = linha.split(" ")
recebido0=0
recebido1=0
send1=1

for linha in ref_arquivo:
    if (valor[0] == "0"):
        if ( valor[1] == "RECEBIDO" ):
            recebido0 = recebido0 + 1
            print ("RECEBIDO 00000")
        elif ( valor[1] == "SENDING" ):
            send0 = send0 + 1
            print ("SEND 00000")

    else:
        if (valor[0] == "1"):
            if ( valor[1] == "RECEBIDO" ):
                recebido1 = recebido1 + 1
                print ("RECEBIDO 11111")
            elif ( valor[1] == "SENDING" ):
                send1 = send1 + 1
                print ("SEND 1111")

print ("=========================")
print ('Recebidos [0] =', recebido0)
print ('Enviados [0] =', send0)
print ("=========================")
print ('Recebidos [1] =', recebido1)
print ('Enviados [1] =', send1)

ref_arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeito. Obrigado!!!